# Set up my Service Fabric App to share ports between all services

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric

I'm trying to create an Service Fabric application and I want to be able to call these services through the same port changing only the URL.

**For example:**

I have several services running, by default I have to call:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://myservicedomain-dev.com:[port]/api/controller");
```

And what I want is to access each service calling:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://myservicesdomain-dev.com:80/[myservicename]/api/mycontroller");
```

I didn't find anywhere how to setup this kind of endpoint configuration.

Down here is a link to an image containing the two configurations, I need the one labeled as "Service instances using HTTP on different URLs with port sharing":
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/media/service-fabric-connect-and-communicate-with-services/serviceendpoints.png

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that, you will need to create an API that will route traffic to the appropriate endpoints.

The image that you reference is referring to different ServiceTypes on different ports on the same host process.